# I have a problem with a sscanf() and I can't solve it

Tags: c

I have a line:   Something | Something | Something | Something

I want to use sscanf() to limit the input to " | ".

That "Something" is a string that can include any symbol like ",./@#$ etc."

```
sscanf(line,"%[^'|'] , %[^'|'] , %[^'|'] , %[^'|']",node->x,node->y,node->z,node->w);
//              ^ - I don't know how to put the delimiters.
```

Comment: Just remove the `'` surrounding the `|`.

Comment: `if (sscanf(line, "%[^|] | %[^|] | %[^|] | %[^|]", ...) != 4) /* error */;` and mind trailing whitespace

Comment: You'll still need to actually read the `'|'` characters for example with `" %[^|]|"`

Comment: `strtok` would be a better choice. If "Something" can contain spaces, then writing your own `strtok` using `strstr` to find each `" | "` is probably the best option.

Comment: If we saw the actual sample input -- we wouldn't have to guess.... 2 lines will do.

Comment: How big is `node->x`?  You should specify a width modifier on the `%[` conversion specifier to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: @AdrianMole The `'` is not the major problem.  `,` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`" , "` will scan for optional white-space, a `,` and then more optional white-space.  This is OP's key problem.  It should have been `" | "` to consume the `'|'` separator.

`"%[^'|']"` will scan for characters that are *not*: `'`, `|`.  Use `"%[^|]"` to scan  for characters that are *not* `|`.

`"%[^'|']"` lacks a *width* limit - do not omit a width limit if overflow possible.

`sscanf()` result deserve checking.

Use `"%n"` to record the offset of the scan.  Useful for detecting extra junk in the string.

---

Put it all together

```
struct {
  char x[20];
  char y[18];
  char z[16];
  char w[14];
} node;

int n = 0;
sscanf(line, " %19[^|] | %17[^|] | %15[^|] | %13[^|]%n",
    node.x, node.y, node.z, node.w, &n);
if (n == 0 || line[n]) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Scan failed for <%s>\n", line);
} else {
  Success(); // Your code here
}
```

---

Should `line` contain a `'\n'`, usually that is not wanted either in `node.w`.

```
// sscanf(line, " %19[^|] | %17[^|] | %15[^|] | %13[^|]%n",
sscanf(line, " %19[^|] | %17[^|] | %15[^|] | %13[^|\n] %n",
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a line, use fgets rather than scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *x, *y, *z, *w;
    printf("Enter string: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    char line[100];
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

    x = strtok(line, "|");
    y = strtok(0, "|");
    z = strtok(0, "|");
    w = strtok(0, "\n");

    printf("x:%s\ny:%s\nz:%s\nw:%s\n", x,y,z,w);
}

Enter string: Something1 | Something2 | Something3 | Something4
x:Something1 
y: Something2 
z: Something3 
w: Something4

Enter string: foo
x:foo

y:(null)
z:(null)
w:(null)
```